# How can bot remove all roles from users python

Tags: python, bots, discord, roles

Hello I was wondering how could I remove all roles from all users. If you have any idea let me know I have tried this code but it didn't work.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def rl(ctx):
    guild=ctx.message.guild
    for member in tuple(guild.members):
        try:
            await removeRoles(all)
        except:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure, if there is a function to remove all roles at once. i would solve it with two for loops:

```
async def rl(ctx):
    async for member in ctx.guild.fetch_members():
        for role in member.roles:
            await member.remove_roles(role)
```

ctx.guild.fetch_members() should return all member objects of your guild/server. then you can remove alle roles one after another. maybe not the best way, but it should work. just make sure, that fetch_members() has an async, because its an async iterator.

Answer (score 0):

`removeRoles()` is not a function. I used [`member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20members#discord.Member.roles) to get a list of [`discord.Role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20members#discord.Role)'s then unpacked it into [`member.remove_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20members#discord.Member.remove_roles).

Also, you don't need to make it a tuple.

Here is the final code:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def rl(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    for member in guild.members:
        try:
            roles = member.roles
            await member.remove_roles(*roles)
        except:
            continue
```